# Unable to find which process occupy the port

Tags: port, iftop

I'm running a web server on my machine(ubuntu 16.04).I use iftop to see there is traffic on port 31354.

[image: enter image description here]]

However, when I use lsof -i:31354 to see which process uses this port,I can't see any results, `netstat -tunlp` also.

I checked my code and found there is no replace to use this port.

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in established connections:

```
netstat -ntep | grep <port_number>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried using netstat but could not view this port. I also use "tcpdump -i ens33 port 31354" and found that I did't catch packet on this port, and the same for wireshark filtering.